# child components validation vee-validate

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I am using **vee-validate** to validate my fields and here is my question :

I want to validate forms before submitting and some forms are located in child components
so how can I approach that?

Comment: you need to provide some code, no one can give you a working code without knowing what you have

Answer (score 1):

To have a child component get validated when calling `validateAll`, use vue's provide/inject api to provide the parent validator to the child component:

`inject: ['$validator'],`

https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/injections.html#injecting-parent-validator

Answer (score 0):

for your first concern (validate form before submit) you can do the following according to the documentation

http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#validate-form

**html markup**:

```
<form @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
    <div class="column is-12">
        <label class="label">Email</label>
        <p class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
            <input name="email" v-model="email" v-validate="'required|email'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('email') }" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <i v-show="errors.has('email')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('email')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-12">
        <label class="label">Name</label>
        <p class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
            <input name="name" v-model="name" v-validate="'required|alpha'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('name') }" type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <i v-show="errors.has('name')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('name')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('name') }}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-12">
        <label class="label">Phone</label>
        <p class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
            <input name="phone" v-model="phone" v-validate="'required|numeric'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phone') }" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
            <i v-show="errors.has('phone')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('phone')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('phone') }}</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-12">
        <label class="label">Website</label>
        <p class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
            <input name="url" v-model="url" v-validate="'required|url'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('url') }" type="text" placeholder="Website">
            <i v-show="errors.has('url')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
            <span v-show="errors.has('url')" class="help is-danger">{{ errors.first('url') }}</span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="column is-12">
        <p class="control">
            <button class="button is-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**your vue component**:

```
export default {
  name: 'form-example',
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    url: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          alert('From Submitted!');
          return;
        }

        alert('Correct them errors!');
      });
    }
  }
};
```

About your nested components forms, lets provide us some code so we can help you better